# How to include Android Wear but still support earlier devices

Tags: android, wear-os

I have recently included android wear support in my app but when I went to publish it today I was made aware my earlier version would be archived. My earlier version was targeting api 16 to include as many devices as possible.

I was hoping if a user doesn't have the latest devices capable of running my updated android wear version then they would get the earlier version I have published.

What is the correct procedure to enable this to happen please?

Regards

Comment: As long as you didn't increase the `minSdkVersion` the users should still be able to download the latest version of your app?!

Comment: And they won't get a crash if the app tries to access classes associated with wearable?

Comment: Of course it'll crash... `ClassNotFoundException` and such. That's why you'd use try/except and check the SDK version before attempting to access anything Wear related.

Comment: All classes associated with wearables are in google-play-services-lib or in support libraries. These are independent of system API level so there should be no `ClassNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to keep your app supporting API 16 while adding Android Wear support. The Google Play Services library runs on many older devices, and it will do the right thing to ensure that your code will not crash. Since an old Gingerbread phone cannot support Android Wear, you will just get an error code when you try to make use of Wear functionality, and you can just handle it gracefully with whatever way is appropriate for your application.